# How to extract stack size of all library functions from c code?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, dll, stack

I have few benchmarks like fft, dijkstra. I want to collect the stack size of all library functions and user defined functions. C code is also available.

I am managing cache in hardware, so i need the exact stack size of each small function, variable.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to *improve it*, and explain why do you ask and your motivations.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am managing cache in hardware, so i need the exact stack size of each small function, variable and constant. But For now function is fine.

Comment: On which target processor? Are you porting GCC to some new architectgure? How are you managing the cache?

Answer (score 3):

If compiling with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you could pass the [-fstack-usage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) flag to `gcc` (in addition of optimization flags, if any) which:

> Makes the compiler output stack usage information for the program, on a per-function basis. The filename for the dump is made by appending .su to the auxname. auxname is generated from the name of the output file, if explicitly specified and it is not an executable, otherwise it is the basename of the source file. An entry is made up of three fields:

> The name of the function.
> A number of bytes.
> One or more qualifiers: `static`, `dynamic`, `bounded`.

> The qualifier `static` means that the function manipulates the stack statically: a fixed number of bytes are allocated for the frame on function entry and released on function exit; no stack adjustments are otherwise made in the function. The second field is this fixed number of bytes.

> The qualifier `dynamic` means that the function manipulates the stack dynamically: in addition to the static allocation described above, stack adjustments are made in the body of the function, for example to push/pop arguments around function calls. If the qualifier `bounded` is also present, the amount of these adjustments is bounded at compile time and the second field is an upper bound of the total amount of stack used by the function. If it is not present, the amount of these adjustments is not bounded at compile time and the second field only represents the bounded part.

You could also pass a `-Wstack-usage=`*len* [warning flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), which:

> Warn if the stack usage of a function might be larger than *len* bytes. The computation done to determine the stack usage is conservative. Any space allocated via `alloca`, variable-length arrays, or related constructs is included by the compiler when determining whether or not to issue a warning.

You may consider writing your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to extract the stack size of of functions compiled by a recent GCC (e.g. [GCC 10](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-10/) in October 2020), and since GCC is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), you could improve it.

Of course, if you want the same information for libraries, you should re-compile them from their source code.

BTW, the stack usage of some functions, or of some function calls occurrences, might be ill-defined (and certainly depends upon the optimization flags and the target system), since GCC is *sometimes* capable of [tail call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimizations, and of function [inlining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) (even on functions not qualified `inline`!) and/or [function cloning](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2009-10/msg00279.html). Also, some *few* [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) functions (`printf`, `memset`, ....) are magically known to the compiler which might use some internal [builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) functions to compile them. At last, several softwares (and more and more libraries) are compiled with [link-time optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) (using [`-flto`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)), then the stack usage of individual functions is not well defined (since they are often inlined).

<sup>So I am not sure your question makes any *precise* sense. You might rephrase it and motivate and improve it.</sup>

Comment: Iam printing hello world in main function.  Output of .su file is: -                                                  helloworld.c:4:5:main 16 static                                                                            while i want to check all library function separate. it only display main functions 's stack size and user defined function's stack size. is there any way to find stack size of library functions separate?